# Flutter: Sending variable from one page to another by calling STF widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a flexible navigation system, that uses one page to display different things pulled from a database.
For example
If I would click the button Cars it would navigate to the fixed page (Lets call it display page) And it would pull the title and description from the database and show accordingly. So by clicking Cars, it would send the String Cars with it, so i could use it to find the desired thing from the database.

My question is, how can I send this info to the next page?
I want to use

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Cars"),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HabitPage()));
          },
```

And send the desired item with HabitPage('cars(for example)') (I have studied C and that's how you would send variables, not sure it will work in dart.)

This is my HabitPage

```
    class HabitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HabitPageState createState() => _HabitPageState();
}
class _HabitPageState extends State<HabitPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar
      (
          title: new Text("HabitPage")
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("HabitPage"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Cars"),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HabitPage(info: 'Cars'))); // Passing the info as argument
          },


  
  
class HabitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  HabitPage({this.info}) : super(key: key);
    
    final String info; // Variable to receive the info as argument
  
  @override
  _HabitPageState createState() => _HabitPageState();
}
  
class _HabitPageState extends State<HabitPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar
      (
          title: new Text("HabitPage ${widget.info}")// Showing the info passed as argument
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("HabitPage"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Make this changes in your code.
In the future, you will probably use Named Routes, so you will need this tutorial.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#1-define-the-arguments-you-need-to-pass
But for now, this is the solution

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. Was looking around it for so long, but had forgotten the word arguments... sucks to not have English as my 1st language :D

Comment: So i tried this, and i get a problem,
error: The instance member 'key' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [app] lib\Pages\HabitPage.dart:20)

Comment: Removing this line seems to do the work, don't know if there are any consequences